How to change color of font with array?
I was playing with javascript. I was trying to change color every second without use css. But it only use last item of array. How can I fix this?
const h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
color=["green","orange","blue"]
const myTimeout = setInterval(function() {
for(i=0;i<color.length;i++){
h1.style.color = color[i]
}    
    }, 1000);




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Because for every iteration, the for loop finishes running right away. It always ended up at the last index, which is the color "blue".

Your js run the entire loop every 1 sec, that's why you can only see last color
Use i to store the number of setInterval executions, and calculate index from i in setInterval.


const h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
const colors = ["green", "orange", "blue"];
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => (h1.style.color = colors[i++ % colors.length]), 1000);
<h1>title</h1>




it work. thank so much. what about math.random?

If you want to pick one color randomly, use colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]

@vdt2938 if it works, mark this as the working answer to close as complete.
